# Matrix Representation Question

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$T:V \to R$, $T$ is a linear transformation. Let $B_V = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \}$. Let $B_R = \{r_1,r_2,r_3 \}$. These are basis for $V$ and $R$.

We have:

$T(v_1)= r_1 + r_2$
$T(v_2)= r_2 + r_3$
$T(v_3)= r_3 + 2r_2 - r_1$
$T(v_4)= r_1 - r_3$

Find the matrix that represents $T$ with respect to the basis $B_V$ and $B_W$.

Attempt:

I am not too sure how to solve it. I know that the matrix will consist of the transpose of the coordinate vectors $T(v_1)$,$T(v_2)$,$T(v_3)$ and $T(v_4)$ with respect to the basis $B_W$.

My guess was:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That is correct, but you should use commas between the equations.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Thanks. Why is it correct though ? So are $(1,1,0),(0,1,1),(-1,2,1),(1,0,-1)$ the coordinate vectors of $T(v_1)$ etc ? If so, why ?

Comment: Because that is the *definition* of the matrix of a linear map with respect to bases.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't guess. You should *know* the definition and apply it.

If you fix a basis $B_R = \{r_1,r_2,r_3\}$ then every vector $r$ in $R$ can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of the basis
$$ r = \lambda_1 r_1 + \lambda_2 r_2 + \lambda_3 r_3$$
We then say (i.e. it is a definition) that $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ are the coordinates of $r$.

To find the matrix we must put the coordinates of $T(v_i)$ in the $i$-th column of our matrix. Since
$$ T(v_1) = \color{blue}{1}r_1 + \color{blue}{1} r_2 + \color{blue}{0} r_3$$
the coordinates of $T(v_1)$ are $(\color{blue}{1},\color{blue}{1},\color{blue}{0})$ which we write in the first column of our matrix. Since

$$ T(v_2) = \color{blue}{0}r_1 + \color{blue}{1}r_2 + \color{blue}{1}r_3$$
The coordinates of $T(v_2)$ are $(0,1,1)$ which we write in the second column of our matrix.

etc.